# Why does plaidml tool not work and does my tensorflow code not run?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu, cpu

i do everything like this website [show](https://rustyonrampage.github.io/deep-learning/2018/10/18/tensorfow-amd.html) but when i try to run file python
it give me 2 error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 62, in 
  preload_check
  ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in 
  __init__
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

this error change after i put nucude.dll in windows system32
to this error

```
 [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

and

```
ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this
DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment 
variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is 
not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct 
driver installed.
```

but the line that was shown in link upside work fine

```
import plaidml.keras
plaidml.keras.install_backend()
```

and i chose

```
2 : opencl_amd_hainan.0
```

as my experimental device in plaidml-setup

errors appear in import part :

```
  import os
  import numpy as np
  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
  from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, 
  ZeroPadding2D
  from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
```

everything should work fine because PlaidML, which allows to run deep learning frameworks on many different platforms including AMD GPUs should work.

my laptop is  Intel(R) HD Graphics 520

amd gpu

can those error can be solved or this tool will not work with me